# create PHP array from comma seperated string

Tags: php

I want to be able to create an array like

```
$array = array("one", "two", "three");
```

using a comma separated string

i have tried:

```
$queue = explode(',', $_GET["q"]);
```

but its not creating an array.

when i use

```
foreach($queue as $q) {
    echo $q;
}
```

its just showing one item from the comma separated string rather than all of the items.

If i use the first part of my code (`$array = array("one", "two", "three");`)

then use the foreach loop, it works fine

the value of `$_GET["q"]` is `one,two,three`

UPDATE:

my full code is:

```
$_GET["q"] == '402,403';

$queue = explode(',', urldecode($_GET["q"]));;

foreach($queue as $q) {
        $asm = new AGI_AsteriskManager();
        if($asm->connect()) {
                $result = $asm->Command("queue show $q");
        }
        $asm->disconnect();

        foreach(explode("\n", $result['data']) as $line) {
                if(preg_match("/talktime/i", $line) && !preg_match("/default/i", $line)) {
                        $pieces = explode(" ", $line);
                        echo $pieces[2];
                }
        }
}
```

`$pieces[2]` is only echoing once - it should echo `0` at least but its only showing `0` once

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET["q"]` ?

Comment: please post your string value

Comment: what is you string??

Comment: Try using urldecode($_GET['q']) instead of $_GET['q']

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you string is "one,two,three"

```
<?php
    $_GET["q"] = "one,two,three";
    $queue = explode(',', $_GET["q"]);
    print_r($queue);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

Comment: that's what op trying?

Answer (score 0):

While passing long values through URL, use `urlencode` which is to be used when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

```
$yourstring = "one,two,three";    // your string
$final = urlencode($yourstring);  // url encode it
header("location:yourpage.php?q=$final");   // pass through URL
```

Try to get the URL parameter in another page by decoding the encoded string using `urldecode`,

```
$finalarray = explode(',', urldecode($_GET['q']));
```

Comment: this is still only showing one of the array items. its still working if i use $queue = array("one", "two", "three");

Comment: @Charlie..Try printing the array after exploding and check what you are getting?